# jQuery ajax get API request append element to correct div

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

With Python I have created a feed from Facebook, which is loaded into this:

```
<div class="col-md-12"> 
<section id="cd-timeline" class="cd-container">
{% for item in merged  %} 
<div class="cd-timeline-block">
  <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-success">
            <i class="fa fa-tag"></i>
  </div> <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

  <div class="cd-timeline-content">
    <h2>{{item.1}}</h2>
    <p>{{item.5|safe}}</p>
    {% if  item.2 != '<p> </p>'%} 
    <p> <img src="{{item.2|safe}}"/> {% endif %} <p> {{item.3|safe}} {{item.4|safe}} </p> </p>
    <span class="cd-date">Jan 14</span>
        <div class="timeline-item-post">

   <div class="timeline-options">

    <a href="#"><i class="icon-like"></i> {{item.6}}</a>

    <button id="{{item.9}}"><i class="icon-bubble"></i> {{item.7}} </button>

    <a href="#"><i class="icon-share"></i>  {{item.8}}</a>

    </div>



    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Replay"></textarea>
       </div>  
  </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
</div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->
  {% endfor %}
```

Now if I click the button `{{item.9}}` I want a jQuery request, to load a  JSON response for this element (`item.9` which refers to the post id) without the page being loaded again and attach the div below to `cd-timeline-content` and display the JSON content in it.

```
<div class="timeline-comment">
<div class="timeline-comment-header">
 <img src="assets/images/avatar5.png" alt="">
  <p>Nick Doe <small>1 hour ago</small></p>
  </div>
  <p class="timeline-comment-text">Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
    </div>
```

This was the only idea I had but that looks stupid and it doesn't work.
Copying javascript code for each post seems like a bad idea.

```
{% for item in merged  %} 
<script> 
$("#{{item.9}}").on('click', function() {
  alert('something');
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
        //Handle my response

    });
});
</script>
{% endfor %}
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

Set a class thats the same for each button:

```
<button class="myEvent" id="{{item.9}}"><i class="icon-bubble"></i> {{item.7}} </button>

$('.myEvent').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
    //Handle my response

    });

});
```

with this solution you get the entire json file not filtered by "item". the filter process ve to be done inside the function.

hope this help

Comment: attached it and tried an alert but it is refreshing the page.

Comment: Nope the code is exactly the same as the one you see above

Comment: Cleared my browser now nothings happening ^^

Comment: edited the answer try with that... now i prevent default button actions

Comment: copied it into the console to see if i get any errors Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)